# while loop provide just one block of result using awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am processing my text file using awk. I have written the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
l=1
while [ $l -lt 5 ]
do
echo $l
awk -v L=$l '/^BS[0-5]|^FG[2-7]/ && length<10 {i++}i==L {print}'
l=$(expr $l + 1)
done <input.txt
```

But, once i run the code I just get first awk output. 
Would you please let me know how can I fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop is taking its input from the file `input.txt`.  `awk` is inheriting its input from the while loop, and it reads all of the input on the first iteration of the loop.  In the 2nd iteration, awk gets no data.  If you want to read from that file on each iteration, pass `input.txt` as an argument to `awk`.

Better yet, skip the while loop and do the whole thing in awk:

```
awk  '/^BS[0-5]|^FG[2-7]/ && length<10 && i++ < 5' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not read the lines of our file. Do:

```
while read line && [ $l -lt 5 ]
do
...
```

Comment: OK so basically you just want to loop 5 times? Why not do a `for` loop then?